# Is there a Drupal Wiki documentation site?

Tags: 7

Like on other Drupal support sites, there are many questions and very few answers here.  The community appears to divide into two Drupal groups, coders and users.  I am a user trying to make a website out of the tools available, not invent a new module.

One problem here is that a question quickly gets lost and answers harder to find. I am finding parts of answers at various sites and would be happy to contribute them to a central depository.  Anyone know where that might be?

Added Related Question:
I see a checkbox below the answers box for a Community Wiki. Does this option tag items for use in a Wiki about Drupal?  If so, How do I filter to see them?

Comment: There are a ton of tutorials for Drupal, in 'blogs and videos and otherwise. Also a few paid how-to sites like http://drupalize.me/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://drupal.org/documentation is home to our documentation.  While not usually referred to as a "wiki", most pages are editable by anyone with a drupal.org account.

Also consider connecting with the [Documentation Team](http://drupal.org/contribute/documentation) - there are other users who can help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, I have found a potential Drupal Wiki location on this site. The tags that questioners assign to their questions have brief descriptions and if selected, lead to an expand description.  I have begun to add links and other information to some of these tags.  ***IF YOU LEARN SOMETHING YOU WANT TO SHARE WITH OTHERS, CONSIDER ADDITING IT TO THE TAG DESCRIPTION.***